# CSS positioning question. Please asterisk inside a display block element

Tags: css, css-position

The CMS I am using is generating a code like this for forms:

```
<div class="sf-fieldWrp">
    <label for="Textbox-3">Contact Name</label>
    <input type="text" value="" required="required">
    <p>Your full name please</p>
</div>
```

Now, I would like to place an asterisk next to the label of the fields that are required. The only identifier for required fields in the code is `required="required"`, unfortunately no classes and no ids, only the required attribute.

Is it possible to place the asterisk right **after** the label of the field, in this case after Contact Name?

I tired this CSS code and it kinda works but it places the asterisk before the label and the label itself is a block element but I can change that if needed.

```
label { display: block }
.sf-fieldWrp { position: relative }
input[required="required"] + p::before {
  content: "*";
    color: red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

[Here is how it looks now](https://codepen.io/wpembraced/pen/VwGxyMG)

As you can see the asterisk shows before the label but I want it to show after the label text (not after the label block element).

How do I keep the label and input in two separate lines and place the asterisk after the label text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be able to use the `:has` on the parent and add the asterisk using
after in the label

```css
.sf-fieldWrp:has(input[required="required"]) label::after {
  content: '*';
  display: inline-block;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="sf-fieldWrp">
  <label for="Textbox-3">Contact Name</label>
  <input type="text" value="" required="required">
  <p>Your full name please</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This is perfect. I had to make the input to be "display: block" in order to keep them in two lines though, which is not a big deal. Thank you, Pete!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
label { display: block }
.sf-fieldWrp { position: relative }
label::after {
  content: "*";
    color: red;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

```html
<div class="sf-fieldWrp">
    <label for="Textbox-3">Contact Name</label>
    <input type="text" value="" required="required">
    <p>Your full name please</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this does not check if the field is required or not, it adds the asterisk after all labels and that's not what I wanted. Thanks anyway.